# Vercel access to other URL

Tags: next.js, vercel, next.js13

I want to access another APP URL hosted in VERCEL. How do I do it? The following doesn't work - got a 504 Error. I use Next 13

```
async headers() {
return [
  {

    source: "/xyz.vercel.app/server/user/new",
    headers: [
      { key: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", value: "true" },

      {
        key: "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        value: "GET,OPTIONS,PATCH,DELETE,POST,PUT",
      },
      {
        key: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        value:
          "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
      },
    ],
   },
  ];
},
```